# How to let Magento calculate free shipping on Total Order Incl. TAX

Tags: magento

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this, using magento 1.9.1. I have two different taxes in my shop 6% and 21%;, magento looks at these taxes when putting free shipping on an order.

I've set up Table Rates, where €45+ should be free shipping. Now it does free shipping at around €56 (minus 21% tax brings u somewhat at €45). How can I solve this?

(PS: It seems like Magento 1.9.1 doesnt look at app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/freeshipping.php, because nothing changes after editing this file)

Comment: And you are sure your setup is correct? Ie Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings > Shipping Prices set to 'Including Tax'?

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure. http://oi61.tinypic.com/mukfas.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To respect the tax within the calculation of shipping rates from table rates (regardless of free or non free shipping) you can extend `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate`. Of course it would be better to do so in an own extension but you can also overwrite it in your local code pool. As this is faster and for demonstration I'll show that:

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php`. Now in its `collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)` function just above `// Free shipping by qty` add the following code:

```
if (Mage::helper('tax')->priceIncludesTax()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() + $item->getTaxAmount());
            }
        }
```

With that the base for calculations will include your taxes. This was first discussed (as far as I know) here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/shipping-method-table-rates-magento-v-1-7-always-include-tax-in-order-subtota